# 'Not Connected error' when calling userConfigurationItem.update()

Tags: exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using the ewsjavaapi to create Categories. I am binding to the UserConfiguration, streaming the userConfiguration.getXmlData(), and unmarshalling my into an object using jaxb. I then add my new catagories to the object, then marshall to a byte stream again using jaxb, and use the byte array to update the category data via using userConfigurationItem.setXmlData(), then finally I call userConfigurationItem.update() to apply my changes. My code works perfectly everytime unless the existing categories contain special characters (like kanji), then the call to userConfigurationItem.update() fails everytime with the always useful 'Not Connected error' error. Anyone have a similar issue or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you need to escape special characters within the XML. I'd try adding a category with those special characters via Outlook, then retrieve the XML and see what it looks like. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason. I agree. I did find a flaw in the java ewsapi that I am hoping to fix to correct this issue.